# Controlling the initiation of OS threads vs goroutines?

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

One of the great things about Go, it the fact that it has a massive number of lightweight threads (goroutines) available. This opens up some interesting strategic opportunities, but there are circumstances where Go tends to spawn OS threads; and these are generally limited to a maximum of 10,000 by default. If you happen to exceed that number, things crash.

The following code locks down our max OS threads to 5, and then tries to fire up 10 concurrent goroutines. These goroutines will attempt to use system calls (in this case, file create / write / close), which tends to mean that our goroutine will temporarilly (and exclusively) associate with an os thread. Once the system call stuff is complete, our goroutine will return to being a nice lightweight thread again - sharing an os thread with other goroutines, most likely.

There's a simple solution of course - don't write it like that! In fact, if you take out the file open/write/close, everything will work perfectly... but assuming for the moment, that the code structure below is representative of something bigger and meaner that can't really change a whole lot:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime/debug"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    MaxThreads := 5
    debug.SetMaxThreads(MaxThreads)

    var fileChan []chan string

    // Create 10 channels that we can use to send data to our file writers.
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fileChan = append(fileChan, make(chan string))
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(n int, fChan chan string) {
            threadWriter(n, fChan)
            wg.Done()
        }(i, fileChan[i])
    }

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
            fileChan[i] <- "Test write " + strconv.Itoa(j) + " to chan " + strconv.Itoa(i)
        }
    }

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        close(fileChan[i])
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("All done - success")
}

func threadWriter(i int, dataChan chan string) {
    // Open the file
    f, err := os.Create("tmp/Thread-" + strconv.Itoa(i) + ".txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot open thread file", i)
        return
    }
    // Wait for data to come in.
    for str := range dataChan {
        f.WriteString(str + "\n")
    }

    f.Close()
}
```

So here's the problem: *(threadtest.go)*
I'll run the program 20 times. Sometimes it'll work fine, other times, it'll crash with
runtime: program exceeds 5-thread limit
fatal error: thread exhaustion

```
$ go build    
$ if [ ! -d tmp ]; then mkdir tmp; fi; for i in `seq 1 20`; do ./threadtest 2>/dev/null | grep success > /dev/null; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "all good"; else echo "NOPE - Threads exhausted"; fi; rm tmp/Thread-*.txt; done
NOPE - Threads exhausted
all good
NOPE - Threads exhausted
all good
all good
all good
NOPE - Threads exhausted
NOPE - Threads exhausted
NOPE - Threads exhausted
all good
NOPE - Threads exhausted
all good
all good
all good
all good
all good
all good
all good
all good
all good
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't - it just depends on the timing of system calls, and how many goroutines are in a 'os thread' state at the time. And that's cool.. there has to be a limit on os threads.

However, rather than a panic, if there was some way to detect if we were about to go over the limit, and spin, that might work out ok.. ie:

```
func threadWriter(i int, dataChan chan string) {
    while(debug.OsThreadsActive() > 9999) {
      // spin here until we are safe
    }

    // Open the file
    f, err := os.Create("tmp/Thread-" + strconv.Itoa(i) + ".txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot open thread file", i)
        return
    }
    // Wait for data to come in.
    for str := range dataChan {
        f.WriteString(str + "\n")
    }

    f.Close()
}
```

Unfortunately, looking at runtime/proc.go, there doesn't seem to be an easy interface I can get data from. mcount() is not something that I can query (nor would it be safe to, realistically).

So - does anyone have any suggestions of how, given a goroutine count that exceeds MaxThreads, and a requirement to use potentially blocking os calls within those goroutines, to try and stop hitting MaxThreads? Or, do I just have to put a number-limited mutex lock around any potential system calls within my goroutines, and therefore try to limit concurrent threads on behalf of Go?

Comment: Ideally, the runtime should do this for you, invisibly. Unfortunately it's pretty hard to do and get right. The existing system does have a lot of magic to avoid using blocking system calls when possible, e.g., most file I/O is actually done with a wrapper around `epoll` or kqueues or whatever the system provides.

Comment: Thanks @torek - yeah, when I've written vaguely similar things in C, epoll() is awesome to avoid firing up extra threads.

Comment: Even completely serializing os calls doesn't entirely work.

Wrapping open/write/close in a mutex still fails (roughly 2 in 1000 times).

Comment: My guess there, is that thread reaping is probably covered by the garbage collector - so it's not an instant return to a standard goroutine as soon as the system call completes - hence even mutexing system calls to be serialized, doesn't actually work completely.

Comment: I would avoid tinkering with the thread count unless you have a *very* good reason to do so. It doesn't seem like that's the case - there's no problem statement prompting the thread count change.

Comment: Agreed, Adrian - the default threadcount is 10,000. The example above tweaks it down to 5, just to show the problem without creating 10k+1 files.

For better or worse, the problem I'm solving benefits from having LOTS of files open concurrently - 40k+ is not unusual. At the moment, the open/write/close process for each file, is encapsulated in a goroutine, fed data by an associated channel.

A temporary triage is to restrict #open files to maxthreads (or bump maxthreads, since this is practically the solo app on the OS). Longer term, I think I'll have to restructure.

Comment: I fail to see the point on having 10k+ threads for an equal number of files. This reads  like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Maybe we should try to find out why you need as many threads (or think you do). Or, to put it differently: What is the actual stuff you want to do with 40k+ files *concurrently*? Since I refuse to believe that you have 40k+ cores available on your system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark. There is an element of XY about it, in the context of threads; and in fact, I've resolved the specific problem I'm having, by moving to Y (where Y is a small worker pool, each thread responsible for maintaining N concurrent open files, and using a thread-affinity system based on a fast hash of key elements of my input, to ensure that a particular type of data will always go to a particular thread for processing).

It's a solution for my requirements, but it's not an answer to my original question unfortunately.

(more in the next comment).

Comment: (cont) ie: Although I do need to maintain 40k+ open files (in fact, more would be better), I don't necessarily need 40k+ threads to manage them - it was just architecturally nice to have that option in go when I thought that the number of goroutines was a near inexhaustible resource. ;)

Based on the responses I've seen so far however, if I'm using os calls, channel operations or other features of the language that require an os thread, the number of goroutines is practically limited to the OS threadcount. There is a little elasticity in that number, but once you cross it, you risk crashes.